# Realm Javascript filtered on Date but ignore year

Tags: realm, realm-js

I am attempting to query in RealmJS on a Date field for birthdays.

I want to find all the people that have a birthday today.

The problem is that I can't ignore the year. Is there a way to do this?

My code:

```
const today = new Date();
const morning = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 0,0,0,0);
const evening = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()+1, 0,0,0,0);
const studentBirthdaysToday = realm.objects('Student').filtered('birthday >= $0 && birthday < $1', morning, evening);
```

Even though there are students with a birthday today, it doesn't show because it's looking for the year 2020.

How can I ignore the year?

This is how student.birthday is formatted in the database, it's a Realm Date:
`2000-08-25T10:00:00.000Z`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve this problem easily with a `date` property. I suggest you create a birthday object schema:

```
const Birthday = {
  name: "Birthday",
  properties: {
    year: "int",
    month: "int",
    day: "int"
  }
};
```

and then use it in `Student`:

```
const Student = {
  name: "Student",
  properties: {
    // ...
    birthday: "Birthday"
  }
};
```

You can now filter `Student` on `birthday.month` and `birthday.day`.